# How to redirect unauthenticated users to login page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, session, session-cookies

Im developing a web application using React and Django Sessions with Django Rest Framework for authentication. I have already configured sessions to be given to users on login.

I am trying to find a way to redirect unauthenticated users to login page from any page in the web application.

I have tried to obtain the value of the `sessionid` cookie [seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngov4.png) so that I can redirect users if the `.length` value == 0.

```
    if (getCookieValue('sessionid').length === 0) {
    return <Redirect to="/login" />
}
```

However, since the `sessionid` cookie is an **HTTP** cookie, **JavaScript** is unable to obtain the value. Thus, it is always 0.

How can I obtain the value of the HTTP cookie? Or, is there any other way to achieve my desired effect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a cookie value (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641531/get-a-cookie-value-javascript)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/document/cookie

Comment: @SumnerEvans Thanks for the reply. Unforturnately, it does not as ```document.cookie``` is not able to obtain the value of the ```sessionid``` cookie. It does not even show up in JS as it is a HTTP cookie.

Answer (score 0):

This is the purpose of HTTP-only cookies -- making them inaccessible to Javascript. Your Javascript needs to make a request to the Django API and store the session ID on the client side (using LocalStorage or similar mechanism) or interpret a redirect order from the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any variable in Django session. It is a dictionary and you can use the session variables in any view.
You can do something like this:

**#In login request handler**

```
def login(request):
   #your code here and
   #if_credentials_are_correct_then:
   request.session['user_id']=UserID
```

Now just add this line of code in your views:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
def anyView(request)
    try:
       if request.session['user_id']:
          #your code for authenticated user
       else:
           return redirect('login_url/')  
    except:
       return redirect('login_url/')
```